# Ruby loop through hash and run function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to loop through this hash, and use `Zlib.inflate()` function to decompress the values of each of the given keys, then print the output in JSON.

```
 {"event_id"=>1, "a_full"=>"x\x9C\xD3\xD5M\xB4L40\xB10N\xD4u\xD4\xD5\xE5\x8A64\xD2w,(\xD27204\xB320\xB326\xB226W\xD0\xD55010\x88U\b+\xAF\xF2\xAF\xF0\xB0pttt\x05b\xA3\"\x97\xFCr \xED\xE8\xA6`hn\xA4gh\x01A\xC6\n\xA6\x86\x96\xA6F\xC8b\x86\xE6\n\x16\x06\\\x00cf\x18\x88", "b_full"=>"x\x9C]\x8F\xCBn\xC20\x14D\xF7\xF9\x8A\xBB,\xD4\x8F\x84@\nA]P\x84\xA0\x02\xDA\xAA\x04em\x9CK\xB0pl\x93\x84\x87\xF8\xFA\x06J7\xDD\x8D\x8Ef43\x94\x8A\x81\xF0\xBB\xFDP\xD07J\xBD\xE9$\x01\x0E\xB3$\xF9\xE2\x01\v\xBC\x99\xAD\xEA\x18j\xACj\xB7s\xECt\xD4\xE6\x8C\e&m\xE1\x8D\xAD1(keM\f{DG\x85V'\xF4FR\xA2\xBBG.5\xDF\xD5\x85&\xC29\xAD\xA4\xB89\xF9\xE5F\x9E/\xFFi\xA1\x87\x87W\x9F\r\x88*D\x8E\xBC\xA9p\xA4\xCD\xDBw\xD8\xF7\xD6./E\x86\xF4\xDDT(\x8F%\xD2o<\x1C\x9BEU\f\x81\xB7\xAE\xB0\xA4\xA3\x1CM\xD3\xB9\xB4W\xA5\xB5\xE0=\xE6\xC3S\xAALf\xCF\x15|$\x10\xB1p\b\xE9g\x1Au[0jz1\xC5\xCD\\\xD5\xBC\x17\xBE\xB00\x82\xA7\xF9,Y.\bh\xB5G\x98\xA2\xDC\xDB\x16\x8Cw\xA5-\x90w\a\xCCg\x9D\xA8\x13\xB2 \xF0a%\xB6\xA2T\x8F\xD8\xE3)\x9D\x18i3e\xF2\x18\xF2\xABr\x042\xDCjQ#\x81*\x93\xBB?\xD3B\x98\xFC\xD8\\\x8B\x01\r]\xAF\b\x9A\xDFoD\x94w\x11\x91\xEAt\x17]\xCF\xFB\x01\xE4\xC6\x7F\b", "c_full"=>"x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", "e_full"=>"x\x9C\x85W\xEBS\xDB\xB8\x16\xFF\\f\xF8\x1FT\xDF\xB9\x1D\x98\xA9\xA3\x00iJ!\xCE^\x1E\xE9\xC0\x0Em3K\xB6\xBD\xFB\x89\x91m\xC5\xD6V\xB6\\IN\xC8n\xF7\x7F\xDF\xA3\x87\x1D'\x90\x96\x19\b\xD2y\xE8\xFC\xCE;aH\xDE\x91\xFE\xE0\xF4\x84\x84\x930\xDC\e\xBD\xBC\xFEt5\xFBc:A7\xB3\x0Fwh\xFA\xFB\xE5\xDD\xED\x15\nB\x8C\xBF\x9C\\a|=\xBBv\x84A\xAF\x7F\x84f\x92\x94\x8Ai&J\xC21\x9E|\f\xF6\xF7\x82\\\xEB\xEA\f\xE3\xE5r\xD9[\x9E\xF4\x84\xCC\xF0\xEC7\x9C\xEB\x82\x0F0\x17B\xD1^\xAA\xD3`\xBC\xBF72w\xE3\xD1\xCB0D\xB7\xA5\xD2\xA4L\xE8%\xCDX\x894-*N4\x8D\x02<\xF3\xFF*\\\x10V>\xA4\xAB\x92\x14,yh8z\xE9R\xF7\xAA\xBC\nP\"R\xFA\xA9\xD6\x8A\xA5\xD4Xw\xAB\xEED\xF2\x95\xA6Q0'\\\xD1\x00\x85\xA1}\x91\x92\xD4|\x16T\x13d\xEC\f\xE9\xB7\x9A-\xA2\xE0J\x94\x9A\x96:\x9C\xAD*j\x94\xD9S\x14h\xFA\xA8\xAD\xE9\xE7(\xC9\x89TTGL\x89\xF0\xF4\xF4\xCD\xBB\xF0\xD8`\x00]O\xEC\x9F\xA4L\x93\x98S\x04\xB6\x02\x86T$u\x01\xDA\x1E4\xD3\x9C>\xC8\xACl\xAC\xB1\x17\xE3\eQP$\xE6\xE8\"\xA9K\xAA\xD9#\xBA\x90z\x84\x1DmK\xFD\xA4L[\xE5N\x05g\xE5W$)\x8F\x02\xA5W\x9C\xAA\x9CR\x1D\xA0\\\xD2\xB9\xBF\xE9%J\x05H\x03,\x8F\xC6\x9C\xB7\xF5>g\xB6q\x15\x95\xAAk\xAF\x11\xC9\xA9\xA4(\x13T!\xCF\xD0~\xAEyv\x9B\xAB\x12\xC9*\x8D8)\xB3\x9Ad\xF0\xCA\xAFdA\xEE\xED\xE5\x86\x91\x9Dk\xAFt\x7Fo^\x97\x89I4\xF4\xE1\xC3\x03 \x16$\x9D\x82\x8A\x03V2}\x88\xFEF\bcw\xAB\x90\xCE)Z\xB22\x15K\xC4\xE6\xE8#Y\f\xC0E\x8A\xFDE\xD3\xFD=d\xAE\xACP\x14iY\xD3C\xE0\xD49:(\xC9\x82eD\v\t\xBA\f\xC7\x01\xA9\xAA\x8F\xC6\x11Q\xF0\x91j\x95\x10\xC8\x8B\xC3W\xAF\x0E*\x93\x05\xB7\xA56\xF4\xCF\x00\e\f:\x8C\xA2\xC1!\x88\x19\xE5\b5\xE1\xEE\x81\x99U\xF6%beI\xE5\x17\x96\xEA\xFC|\x8Bv\xE3h7\x94e\xB9>G\xA2tFF\e\xF8\xCE\xD1?\xFF\x18\xC5\x14\xB2\xD8\x9B\xDE\xE8{\x19m\xBD\x85\xBE\x7FG\x1D\x95\xDB\xF4\x9BC\xC4EB\x8C\x0F{\xEE\x81\x83\xC3\xF3\xFD=P\xBF\xE9Q\xEB\x16 `\xEC\x82\x86]\xD4\\\xB6\xE3\xA6\x84b\x91\xAE\xC6\b\xFEI\xD9\x021(4S\xA0wdEe\x80l\xE6EA%\\k8#\xB1\x12\xBC\xD6\x00fi\f?{\xDB\xEFW\x8F\xE7\xE8\xAF\x10\x82D\x1F\xCF\x8El\x90\xD7z\x946\x8F\x04F;B\xA3\xFC\xC8^\x83*j\x02\x12\x8CG\xC4'x\xA7\xD1\x10_<\xBDD\x14\x18XX\x91!%\x93(`\x05@R\xD0x2\xD1\xCB\xD8<p\x16D\xC1I\x7F\bub\xFD\x04\x87\xD3\x00\xC5BB\x1AGA\x1F\xA41\x81\xDF\xFCh\f\xE1t&\f[\x13n\xCB\xB9\b\xC6\xB3\xC9\xFD\f\x912E\xD7\xB4\x10\x90\xED\xD2z\x15\x19\x064\x17r]\xCB_h\x8C>\xD7\x1CbBb\xC6\x99^\xA1\xFB\x84\x98\x10\x81\xFE\xE1\xD8*opg\\\xC4\x84C\xB6z\xE0\xE6\xE7\xC5\xC8U\xCF\xDA8\x94P\xCE+\x92\xA6\xAC\xCC\xDA\xB3\xAAH\xD2\x9C=\xBE\xA3~\xFF\xBF\x80DKx\x04\xB4\xA4\x88p\x96\x95Q\xC0\xE9\xDC\xD6\xD4\x8B\x17\xAD\em\x10l\x17\x1D\xE7\xD0\x8B\fz\xF4\x1D\xB5d\xC8\x18\x9A\t\xC9\xA8r<\xEB\xF36'\x91\x9A)\xED\xD9\xFC\xC1\xBE\xB4\xC5\x972\x95p\xC2\n*\x1D\xEB\xFA\xFC\xF4m\xE9\xFA\xFBx%j\x89\xCC\xD1\xB3l \xC8j\xAAt,\xC4W\xC7\xDB\x1E\x9F\xE3\xBD\xF8\xF5\xE2\xFF\xB8\x03\xD9\x9Cm\x18\r\xB3\xF1\x15\xD6\xE9\x96\xCF\xA4\xC9\x12\xEF\xB4\x86\x8A\xC1\xB3\xF0\xC7D\xC7\x85\x11C\x1Cm=\xB4\xFF\x98VH!G\x9A\x846=\x10\xB5##\xB6\xA3\xCEO\x9Ag\x9A\xE7s=\xD9sw{r\x93=\x9Ed\xAD\x1C\xE5\xC7\xF6\xAE\x82\xD4w%\xB3\xA4<1cF\vd\xFCh\b\x90\x80\xC7\x86\xD9g \x04@)33\x84\\y\xA8\xF9\xC9x\x06\x8E|.\xAB?\xDF\xF7@\xFE\xC4\xCB[\xC4\r\xF2\x9F\xCE\x00\xA0\x1A\xAFl \xEF\x00\x81F|IdS\xFC\xCD\xAD\xA2D&y[\x19#0\xA7@\xC4\xCE\x83\x86h\xC2\xF9\vl\n:\xFAVS\x00\x81`\xC8\xE7\"\xB5mHwjj\xC4IL\xF9\xD8\t!\x9BQ\xEEf\xCD\xC1\xCA\xAA\xD6\xDE\xE7\x8E\xEF\xBD\x90\xDD\x01\x05-\xCEtj\xA8\xB2`\x87X&.k\xADE\xD9H\xA9:.\x18\xC8-\b\xAF-y\x8D\x05\e0\x1Eo\x93<\e\xD0-\xCC;\x98\xF4j-Tw\xED\xE5l\xBC\xB3\\/\xA5X\xC2\xE8\xD8\xACZ\x80\xCCv\xC8o\x14\xB1\x17\xF6w?\x91\\\x17\xEB\x1F\xDDb\xFD\x81\x04teV:\x91{\xA8\xB4\xBAj\xF9]buykE%\x83\xE6\xDBy\xA1\x92b\xCE8\xFD\x81\xD0Vc\xF8\x04B\e\xCD\xA1\x11{\xB1!\xF5\xC3\x16\xD1y\xA9\x03l\x84\x9B\x80l\x87\xD0\x17\x16\xCCW\x88@\xBA\x15E(!{c\x8B\xE9\xA7\xA1\xDD1\xEF\xC0y4\xA9\xA5\x19.[.\xDFvGG\x01M8\xE4\x15Q+;1\xDFK\xA8%\xC2\xC3\xC9c\xC5\x85\xA4\xD2\xA37\x9Bo0\xF6D\xD4\x10\xB7\x83\xBA\e\xBBI_\x92.\xA8\\\xD7\xDF\xA8\x1A\xB7\xD8D\xFC'\xD8\xE0<d{\x18\x87\x8F\xB3\xEB\xE3\xB7W\xD7\x97\xC3Ix1\x19^\x87GG\xC9<|7\xBC<\r\a\x83\xC1\x9B7'o\x06}\xF8q\xFB~L\x14mA\xC1\xB6W\x9A\x15\xA6W\x90DB\xAFK\x19\xB1\xD0\xAA:\xC6*\x87/\x03K\xB2\xA08\x81U\x04\xCF\xE1\xC1\x1C\xAB\xA5\xFD\xEC\xC1\xD5\x7F\x16n\x93\x8B\x86\xAF\xFB\xAF\x8F\xDF\xBD\xEE\x8E\xD1\xB7\xEB5a8\fZ\xE3\r\x12\"I\xE1\xCB\xBD\x10\vF\xDB\xEA~o\x1F\x80!\xDD\x83Gv\xC9|\xAB\x89]\b\x9CL\x0EOt\x19i\x11\xD3\xD4\xAD0\x9B\xDA\x90\x97\xB3\x12\xA8\xE25\x94\x90\xAA\xEC2\xDD\t\xEF\x96\x13\xD6\x0Eh\xDC\xE4#\x9Cd\xEC\x97\xE9\xD1\xC3T\x8A\xF4\xC1\xAF\xB3\xD1}\xC3l\x1Fn\x1A\x18\xEC\xBB\x9C\xB9\xED\x11?\x86\xAD\xC2p\xEE\x98v\xF9k\x84-\x92u\xD0\xB1\x8B\xFA\xB8\xC9\x9Dj\xC7\xF8\\O\n\x98\b1\x91~z\xAE\xDBb\xBB\x8C!\xF4\xF3\n\xB9\x88\x05\xB4\xE6\xDF\x9F\xAC,\x95d\v\x92\xAC\\\x9DO\xDD\x01M\x05 ]m\xB3\xC2~\xCB\xB58[.\xD4\xFF6u\x9B\xEF\x8EP!\xCFh\xC7\x1F\xC0\xAD\xBF\xD1%\xD4&}\x00\xB7V\xB0\x9A\x9A\x8F'|yeH7\xB3\xD9\x14MM\x86PM\xA51\x03\x96f\xF0\xB7g\x7F\x95\x88ju~\xDC\xEF\x0F\x8D\xC7\xDAa|\a\x8BJ\xC7o\xC8/\xAD\xE6\xEF(\x96k\x9F\x9AO\xBB\xB4?\x9D\xD0\xC6\xB7#\xFB=\x17\x88{\xFF\x02+&\xFC\xD8", "f_full"=>"x\x9C=\xCCA\v\x820\x14\x00\xE0\xFB~\xC5\xBB\xC7\xD3M-l\xD1\xA5@\x84\x82vX\xD0u\xCC\x87\n\xB6\x85>1/\xFD\xF6\xE8\xD2\xF5;|\x88n\xEFdQ\xE6\x0E+DQ[kR\x95(\xC8\xA4\x84\xDBE\x9Cc`\n\x8Cv}\x91\x06\xA67\xA7\x1D?\x87\x03\xF8\xCE\x8D\x13\xF1\xF1n+,\xC5\x03M\\h\xA4\x06O\xAB\x06S\x9Bt\x9B\xE4\x89\x92\xA8>\xC3\xEC\xFBf\x93\xCD\xCB\xD4\xF6\xD9\xFF\xBBRh\xB9\xD3P\xC8\xFD\xEE\x87\x81<\xF71h\xF0C\x9CH\x88/'s.\"", "h_full"=>"x\x9Cu\x90Mj\xC30\x10F\xF7:\xC5\x90U\f\x91mYr\x12\xBBh\x914\x86,\xFAG\xDD\v\xA8\xD24\x0E\x8D%#\xDBus\xFB*i!\xAB\"x\x1A\x867\f\xDFP\xAA\n\x95\x8A5WtO)\xD9tJ7H\xF7\xCA\x9A\x13\xFA\x12:\xEF\xBE\xCF\xB4G\xFF\x85\x9E\xD4\x83\xEB&5\xE8\xA6\x04&\x96\xA9\xC8W,_\xAEx\x911\x06\"-x!`N!\xBC\xE8\xA6f\xFF\xBAw\xA0]\xFB~\xB4h$\xE7\xD9\x02:&\xD7\x81\x99\xE4\xE9*\xFC\\\xB2@qe.\x99X@\xEFe\x1A8]Z\xA7Ky\xD02%\xAF\xD8w\xCE\xF6H\xB7\xCE\x9C\xE9\x9BW\xB6\xFFp\xBEES\xC2\x0Eu3\xDAO4\xE4\xC5;3\xEAK\xA0Ggj\xD4\xA3?\x0Eg\b\x1E\xFC\x06N\xB2\xB8\x88\x19\xCC\x9Ba\xE8\xCA$\x99\xA6)n\x9D\xE9\xFF\xC4\xD8\xF9C\x12\xC5\xA4\xBE\x9E\xA1\xBC\xCDd1\xCBa~\x8Fvx\xAE#R\xD9CHC\xC3\x06,aV=m\xB6\x0F\xD5nF\xC8\x0Fa\x10g\xFE", "i_full"=>"x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", "k_full"=>"x\x9C\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01", "z_full"=>"--a9a0483a-Z--\n", "compressed"=>true}
```

Here is a Pastebin [link](http://pastebin.com/raw/95uNtR1C#)

When I tried using `.each` method, I got `NoMethodError: undefined method 'data' for main:Object`

My goal is to loop through this hash, and pass values to Zlib.inflate(a_full), then b_full ..etc

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

```
p h.map{|k,v|[k,Zlib.inflate(v)] rescue[k,v]}.to_h.to_json
```

Comment: I know inline `rescue` is supposed to be evil, and I know why.  But I actually like this. Are there any cases where rescue would trap an error that you did not want it to?  I think not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Rails, this should work:

```
hash = { event_id: 1, a_full: 'asdadadsd', b_full: 'asdfasdfsdf' }

hash.except(:event_id).each do |key, value|
  Zlib.inflate(value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to preserve the keys in the hash and convert the deflated result to JSON, you can do something like:

```
hash = { event_id: 1, 
         a_full: 'asdadadsd', 
         b_full: 'asdfasdfsdf', 
         z_full: 'dddsds', 
         compressed: true }

hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), result|
  result[key] = key.to_s =~ /_full/ ? Zlib.inflate(value) : value
end.to_json

# => "{\"event_id\":1,\"a_full\":\"deflated asdadadsd\",\"b_full\":\"deflated asdfasdfsdf\",\"z_full\":\"deflated dddsds\",\"compressed\":true}"
```

This example deflates all values in the hash of the `*_full` keys and leaves the rest untouched. At the end, the resulting hash is converted to JSON.

Comment: A small suggestion: write your block variables `|(key,value), result|`. You might also consider using the ternary operator here.

Comment: Thanks Cary, I didn't know it was possible to write the key / value assignment like that, that is cool!